# Can you reset the selected value for an array of SelectItems?

Tags: html, typescript, primeng

I have a p-dropdown in an html file that has its options mapped to an array of SelectItems in a primeng typescript file.

I'm pretty sure this is pretty simple, but I'm try to figure out how to manually set what is selected.

Here is the dropdown and its SelectItems.  Upon loading, the first item is selected.

```
<p-dropdown [options]="myItems"></p-dropdown>

myItems: SelectItem[] =
[
  { value: "firstVal", label: 'firstLabel' },
  { value: "secondVal", label: 'secondLabel' },
  { value: "thirdVal", label: 'thirdLabel' }
];
```

However, what if I want to have the second or third value selected upon loading (or even at some point later)?

Thanks much.

Comment: Hello, if I understand you correctly
The problem is that when you give the data to the list, the default is the first value selected, and you want a solution where the default is not selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[(ngModel)]` to `p-dropdown` and bind it with property like 'selected_value':

```
selected_value:SelectItem;

myItems: SelectItem[] =
[
  { value: "firstVal", label: 'firstLabel' },
  { value: "secondVal", label: 'secondLabel' },
  { value: "thirdVal", label: 'thirdLabel' }
];
```

Inside `ngOnInit()`:

```
//here assign which value you want to the `selected_value` 
this.selected_value = this.myItems[0];
```

in HTML:

```
<p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="selected_value" [options]="myItems"></p-dropdown>
```

Comment: Thank you.  For some reason it's not working for me.

selected_value should just be declared as a member variable in the ts file like so correct?

selected_value: SelectItem;

Comment: You're welcome. First, make sure to import `FormsModule` inside the app module .
yes it should be as member variable in your component class.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what was wrong - thanks!